# Why 1-bit multiplier is not expandable like 1-bit full adder does?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

1-bit full adder is intended for add two binary operand (with size 1-bit). It has 3 inputs, that is first operand, second operand, and carry-in. Also it has 2 outputs, that is sum and carry-out.

1-bit full adder is expandable because if there's 1-bit full adder more where carry-in is connected to the carry-out of the another 1-bit full adder, it will create 2-bit adder that is intended for add two binary operand (with size 2-bit). So we can conclude n-bit adder is consist from many 1-bit full adders.

But why it's not applied to the 1-bit multiplier?
What I mean with 1-bit multiplier is just simply an AND gate with two inputs and 1 output.

How do I make exapandable with just daisy chaining a 1-bit multiplier?

Comment: Have a close look at the Booth multiplier and then improve your question.

Comment: For multiplying, *sign* of the two operands is of most fundamental concern. When considering **sign**, an XOR function provides the proper two-input result. If you expand to more than two inputs, *parity* function is correct.

Comment: Think about the structure of what you are doing.  Add 2 one digit numbers and the most you get is two digits.  The second being a carry.  9+9 =18.  Multiply 2 one digit numbers and you get two digits.  9x9=81.  It is not expandable.

Comment: If "time" is not of concern, try the "serial" multiplier.

Comment: Remember your math lessons in primary school. How did you add, and how did you multiply? Reduce this to binary values, and you will find that multiplication works with addition, which will include the expansion you look for.

Comment: @thebusybee I have been used your method, yes it's extendable but not simply daisy chaining two multiplier with same size like how full adder did. For example 2-bit multiplier need atleast two 2-bit full adders. 4-bit multiplier need atleast four 4-bit full adder.

Comment: That is correct. However, you don't need the same sizes on the two operands. You can build a multiplier for 2-bit by 5-bit giving you a 7-bit result. Isn't math cool?